# How to create Wepay account and How to get client_id and client_secret from account?

Tags: go, wepay

I want to integrate wepay in my application for payments. I have created wepay account but unable to find client_id and client_secret on application dashboard. How I can find client_id and client_secret as these two fields are required to create weapay checkout. Any help would be appreciated.